# Adding a webApp to Tomcat Embedded dynamically

Tags: java, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

I need to understand why using the below code to add a webapp dynamically to the embedded tomcat giving the following error, when we add Context on startup everything works fine, the code is the same.
Code:

```
/*
 * Add a context to the host and contexts map; be careful to call this only
 * within a synchronization block of this.contexts
 */
private Context addContextDynamically(String contextPath, String folderName) {
    logger.info("Adding context " + contextPath + " at " + folderName);

    Context contextNew = this.embedded.addWebapp(this.host, contextPath, folderName);
    // Context contextNew = this.embedded.addContext(this.host,contextPath,
    // folderName);
    // this.embedded.addContext(host, contextPath, dir)
    // logger.info("contextNew-->"+contextNew);
    List<File> filterdJarfiles = getAppJarFilesAlone(folderName);
    WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(contextNew);
    for (File jf : filterdJarfiles) {
        String st = jf.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, jf.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.separator));
        logger.info("st-->"+st);
        resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/lib", st, "/"));
    }
    logger.fine("Adding context setResources " + resources);
    logger.fine("Adding context contextNew "+ contextNew);
    logger.fine("Adding context filterdJarfiles " + filterdJarfiles.toString());
    try {
        contexts.put(contextNew.getPath(), contextNew);
        contextNew.setResources(resources);
        INexxWebappLoader loader = new INexxWebappLoader(contextNew.getParentClassLoader(), contextNew);
        contextNew.setLoader(loader);
        // host.addChild(context);
        cleanContextWorkDir((StandardContext) contextNew);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Caught exception while adding context :"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contextNew;
}
```

The error we get is :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting static Resources
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setResources(StandardContext.java:2470)
at com.medicity.iNexx.AppServer.addContextDynamically(AppServer.java:541)
at com.medicity.iNexx.AppServer.monitorEnablements(AppServer.java:439)
at com.medicity.iNexx.AppServer.run(AppServer.java:345)
at com.medicity.iNexx.AppServer.init(AppServer.java:244)
at com.medicity.iNexx.AppServer.main(AppServer.java:335)
```

So basically our product downloads the zip and unzip it in the web app directory and in the server.xml we have set:

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `Context` to a running `Host`, it will be started automatically unless the property `startChildren` is set to `false` on the `Host` component. You probably don't want this, since your `addContextDynamically` needs to configure the context first.

Therefore in the method used to configure Tomcat you need to call:

```java
final Host host = this.embedded.getHost()
if (host instanceof ContainerBase) {
    ((ContainerBase) host).setStartChildren(false);
}
```

and you need to add to `addContextDynamically`:

```java
final State hostState = this.embedded.getHost().getState();
if (hostState.isAvailable() || LifecycleState.STARTING_PREP.equals(hostState)) {
    contextNew.start();
}
```

Cf. the [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/aaac41d281df19c735f4c0bb906f8e085e01080f/java/org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase.java#L724) for more information.

**Remark**: Contexts added before the `Host` starts are immune to the `startChildren` property.

Comment: `((ContainerBase) this.embedded.getHost()).setStartChildren(false);`

is what my eclipse is allowing me to write without error. tomcat embedded 8.5.27 is the version

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you. I modified the answer accordingly.